# From the estimator of the population to the estimator of the subpopulation (Proportion)

Tags: proportion, bias

Say you have a population of size $N$ that can be divided into subpopulations of men and women. The subpopulations are respectively of size $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that $N_1 + N_2 = N$. However, $N_1$ and $N_2$ are unknown.

Say you then take a simple random sample without replacement of size $n$ in your population. You'll then end up having a sample of size $n_1$ in the subpopulation of men and a sample of size $n_2$ in the subpopulation of women such that $n_1 + n_2 = n$. On each individual, we ask them if they are left or right-handed.

I am asked to find the bias of the estimator of the proportion $p_1$ of left-handed individuals in the subpopulation of man and then the same thing, the proportion $p_2$ of left-handed individuals, in the population of women.

I know that I can express $P = (N_1*P_1 + N_2*P_2) / (N_1+N_2)$, where $P$ is the true proportion of left-handed in the popuation of size $N$, $P_1$ is the true proportion of left-handed man and $P_2$ is the true proportion of left-handed women.

I can also express that same thing for the estimator of the proportion in the sample: $p = (n_1*p_1 + n_2*p_2) / (n_1 + n_2)$. I tried using this to find the expected value of $p_1$, knowing that $E(p) = P$. However, I hit a wall at one point because I'm stuck with $E(p_2)$ which I don't know. If I do plug it into my equation, I get $0 = 0$.. Which is true but doesn't help much!

Any ideas or clues?

*Edit*
I'm referring to this estimator:

$p = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \in S} y_k$, where $S$ is my sample, $y_k$ is the $k$-th individual of the sample and $y_k$ can either be 1 or 0.

Comment: You haven't stated whether you know the gender of each individual in the sample: do you?  And which estimator are you referring to?

Comment: @whuber, the gender of each individual in the sample is random since I have to take into account every possible sample. I'm referring to this estimator:

$p = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \in S} y_k$, where $S$ is my sample, $y_k$ is the $k$-th individual of the sample and $y_k$ can either be 1 or 0.

Comment: Right: but do you know the genders or not?  If you don't know them, how will you be estimating the proportions left-handers of each gender?  And if you do know them, then you have two random samples--one of women and one of men--so what is there left to say?

Comment: Well, if I'm given the actual sample I _do_ know the genders. In that case, it's quite easy to find the estimator for both men and women: $p_i = \frac{1}{n_i} \sum_{k \in S_{n_i}} y_k$, or something along those lines.

Unless I'm getting confused, I don't see how this helps me figure out the bias of $p_1$.

Comment: Haven't you computed the bias for any random sample?  You have two random samples, one of males and one of females, so apply your results.

Comment: Are you suggesting that since I know that $p$ is unbiased, then so are $p_1$ and $p_2$? I guess that'd make sense.